# Copy an entire row from sheet 2 which contains any value from column A on sheet 1

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, formula

I would like to be able to copy any row from sheet 2 which contains any value from column a in sheet 1. I so far have this code but keep getting subscript out of range errors. Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks

```
Sub test()
Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
Dim row_counter As Long, col_counter As Long

Set MyRange = Sheets(“Sheet1”).Range("A1")

For Each MyCell In MyRange
If Cell.Value = MyCell.Value Then
Cell.EntireRow.Copy
   End If

Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean `If MyCell.Value = MyRange.Value`? There is no variable here defined as `Cell` so something is off in your `If` statement

Comment: Do you understand that you're iterating over ***single*** cell?

Comment: Also you're doing `.copy` but not `.paste` ...